# Userscript for creating a confirmation popup whenever submitting an issue or posting a comment via pressing Ctrl+Enter(the built-in hotkey) in GitHub

Tags: javascript, forms, greasemonkey, ctrl, modifier-key

Test URL: https://github.com/darkred/test/issues/new

GitHub allows in the issues area for a public repo:

- submitting a new issue with just 1 character as title and no body, and
- posting a comment with just 1 character .

The above happens to me quite a lot because the build-in hotkey for 'submiting an issue or comment' is <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>: I accidentally press that keyboard shortcut before my issue/comment text is ready.

So, I'm trying to make a script (using Greasemonkey) that would show a confirmation popup whenever I try to:

- submit a new issue, or
- post a comment

via pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>:
if user presses <kbd>Ok</kbd> in the popup, then the script to allow the submit,
but if the user presses <kbd>Cancel</kbd> in the popup, then the script to stop the submit.

<strike>I've come across these two approaches:</strike> 
After the helpful comment by Brock Adams I have the following code:

```
var targArea_1 = document.querySelector('#issue_body');         // New issue textarea
var targArea_2 = document.querySelector('#new_comment_field');  // New comment textarea

function manageKeyEvents (zEvent) {
    if (zEvent.ctrlKey && zEvent.keyCode == 13) {   // If Ctrl+Enter is pressed
        if (confirm('Are you sure?') == false) {    // If the user presses Cancel in the popup
            zEvent.stopPropagation();               // then it stops propagation of the event 
            zEvent.preventDefault();                // and cancels/stops the submit submit action bound to Ctrl+Enter
        } 
    }
}

if (targArea_1 !== null) {targArea_1.addEventListener('keydown', manageKeyEvents);}
if (targArea_2 !== null) {targArea_2.addEventListener('keydown', manageKeyEvents);}
```

Now the popup appears ok whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>.
**The problem is that the issue/comment is not submitted when pressing <kbd>Ok</kbd> in the popup** (even if I haven't pressed <kbd>Cancel</kbd> in the popup before, at all).  How to fix this?
And, how to re-allow the issue/comment submit after I have pressed <kbd>Cancel</kbd> in the popup once?
In other words: how to re-enable default after preventDefault() ?

Comment: In event listeners in HTML attributes I don't think you need `return`.

Comment: If you have issues with `Ctrl+Enter`, you need to intercept keyboard events on those controls (too).  And, all your event handlers probably need to use `.preventDefault()` and some variant of `stopPropagation()`.  Quick & Dirty  example at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37559790/331508).

Comment: @BrockAdams: Thank you for your useful advices (you put my question on the right track). So I edited my code to intercept the <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd> keyboard shortcut. I tried using `.preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` together (and tried  re-enabling default if user presses Ok) - now the popup appears whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>. The only problem now is that the issue/comment is not submitted when pressing Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the help by user trespassersW [here](https://greasyfork.org/en/forum/discussion/comment/25063/#Comment_25063) *(I thank him a lot)*
i.e. that my code was missing an `else` branch:

```
if (confirm('Are you sure?') == false) {
    // ...
} else {
    var btn = document.querySelector("#partial-new-comment-form-actions button");
    if (btn) btn.click();
}
```

and that's because the `confirm` messagebox clears keyboard events queue.
(therefore the `click 'Ok'` action must be done by the script).

Here is a full working script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @nameGitHub Confirm Create and Close issues
// @include https://github.com/*
// @grant   none
// ==/UserScript==


(function () {      // Self-Invoking function

    function init() {

        // For submitting issues in issue body textarea via Ctrl+Enter
        var targArea1 = document.querySelector('#issue_body');  // New issue textarea
        function manageKeyEvents1(zEvent) {
            if (zEvent.ctrlKey && zEvent.keyCode === 13) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure?') === false) {
                    zEvent.stopPropagation();
                    zEvent.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    var btn1 = document.querySelector('.btn-primary');
                    if (btn1) {btn1.click();}
                }
            }
        }
        if (targArea1 !== null) { targArea1.addEventListener('keydown', manageKeyEvents1); }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // For submitting issues in new comment textarea via Ctrl+Enter
        var targArea2 = document.querySelector('#new_comment_field');   // New comment textarea
        function manageKeyEvents2(zEvent) {
            if (zEvent.ctrlKey && zEvent.keyCode === 13) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure?') === false) {
                    zEvent.stopPropagation();
                    zEvent.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    var btn2 = document.querySelector('#partial-new-comment-form-actions button');
                    if (btn2) {btn2.click();}
                }
            }
        }
        if (targArea2 !== null) { targArea2.addEventListener('keydown', manageKeyEvents2); }

    }

    // Page load
    init();

    // On pjax (because GitHub uses the History API)
    document.addEventListener('pjax:end', init);

})();
```