# Userscript for creating a confirmation popup whenever pressing Ctrl+Enter or Enter in the title textbox of a new issue page in GitHub

Tags: javascript, forms, greasemonkey, ctrl, modifier-key

*(In continuance of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38721405/3231411))*

I've been trying to make a script (using Greasemonkey) that would show a confirmation popup whenever I attempt to:

- submit a new issue, or
- post a new comment.

via pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>:
if user presses `Ok` in the popup, then the script to allow the submit,
but if the user presses `Cancel` in the popup, then the script to stop the submit.

The script in the answer above works ok in these cases.

---

I've noticed that, there's an additional way to submit an issue:
press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> while having focus on the **issue title textbox** .

I'd like to cover this with the script, too.

Below is my code.
*if I just open the new issue page (https://github.com/darkred/test/issues/new) in a new tab _(i.e. not via single-page application workflow, aka the History API)_), then the script also works when pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd>.*

**The problem that I still have are that 
if I navigate to the new issue page via following the `New issue`button *(i.e. via the History API)*,

and then I either press <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> or just <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the title textbox, 
then the popup appears momentarily but the submit is not blocked**.

```
(function () {
    function init() {
        var targArea = document.querySelector('#issue_title'); // New issue title
        function manageKeyEvents(zEvent) {
            if (zEvent.ctrlKey && zEvent.keyCode === 13) {      // and the focused element is the issue title textbox
                if (confirm('Are you sure?') === false) {
                    zEvent.stopPropagation();
                    zEvent.preventDefault();
                // } else {
                    // var btn = document.querySelector('.btn-primary');                        // 'Submit new issue' button                
                    // btn.click();
                }
            }
        }
        if (targArea !== null) {targArea.addEventListener('keydown', manageKeyEvents);}
    }
    init();
    document.addEventListener('pjax:end', init); // for the History API
})();
```

STR:

- open https://github.com/darkred/test/issues,
- click the `New Issue` button (you'll get redirected via the History API to https://github.com/darkred/test/issues/new,
- *(You'll notice the focus now is on the issue title textbox)*
  type 123 as issue title and keep the focus on the issue title textbox (leave the issue body empty) ,
- press <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> (or just <kbd>Enter),</kbd>
- notice now that the confirmation popup will appear momentarily,
  but the submit won't be blocked.

What's wrong with my script?

---

For reference here is a list of the GitHub's keyboard shortcuts list: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBMb5.jpg),
that appears when you press ? in the new issue page.

Comment: Try preventing before the `confirm`, and if okay'd, call form's `submit()` directly or use `dispatchEvent`.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Thanks for trying to help. So, I tried preventing before the `confirm`, but, unfortunately, if I change the `manageKeyEvents(zEvent)` into having now `if (zEvent.ctrlKey && zEvent.keyCode === 13) {zEvent.stopPropagation(); zEvent.preventDefault();` and then `if (confirm === ..)` then it doesn't stop the submit.

Comment: Yeah, preventing works for the current event so you need to add a "submit" listener.

Comment: I guess your script isn't the first one in the event chain. Try using `// @run-at document-start` and attach the submit listener to `document`, and inside it check whether the current event.target belongs to a form, in which case prevent the event.

Comment: @wOxxOm: The `blur()` and `focus()` (in my answer below) fixes the issue completely. I deleted my previous 3 comments as irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this **by forcing an unfocus+re-focus on the `#issue_title` element**:
when you open the New issue page, the focus is on the issue title textbox.
The script for some reason wouldn't block the submit. But, if you force an unfocus and re-focus of that element *(using `blur()`(=unfocus) and `focus()`)*, then the script blocks the submit.

Here is the code (always `// @run-at document-end`)

```
(function () {
    function init() {
        var targArea = document.querySelector('#issue_title'); // New issue title
        function manageKeyEvents(zEvent) {
            targArea.blur();
            targArea.focus();
            if ((zEvent.ctrlKey && zEvent.keyCode === 13) || zEvent.keyCode === 13) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure?') === false) {
                    zEvent.stopPropagation();
                    zEvent.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    var btn = document.querySelector('.btn-primary');  
                    btn.click();
                }
            }
        }
        if (targArea !== null) {targArea.addEventListener('keydown', manageKeyEvents);}
    }
    init();
    document.addEventListener('pjax:end', init); // for the History API
})();
```

And here is the complete userscript:
[GitHub - Confirmations before submitting issues and comments](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/22288-github-confirmations-before-submitting-issues-and-comments)