# Javascript - CTRL+Alt+E keydown detection does not work on Firefox 48 and above

Tags: javascript, firefox, mootools, alt, ctrl

At the moment I post this, Firefox is at 49.0.2 version but the bug began to appear since the version 48. I tried a vanilla JS detection, didn't work:

```
document.addEventListener ("keydown", function (zEvent) {
    if (zEvent.ctrlKey  &&  zEvent.altKey  &&  zEvent.code === "KeyE") {
        alert("CTRL+Alt+E pressed!");
    }
});
```

I tried Mootools-More detection, didn't work:

```
var myKeyboard = new Keyboard({
    defaultEventType: 'keydown',
    events: {
        'ctrl+alt+e': toggleTopbar
    }
});
function toggleTopbar() {
    alert("CTRL+Alt+E pressed!");
}
myKeyboard.activate();
```

Didn't try jQuery though.

**Fiddle**: [Detecting combination keypresses (Control, Alt, Shift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557990/detecting-combination-keypresses-control-alt-shift) (credits to Brock Adams)

**Side note**: Also, in the fiddle above, `zEvent.code` always returns the english keys even if you are on an AZERTY keyboard (french keyboard). Maybe the bug is only on AZERTY keyboards (who knows), but I didn't have any other keyboards.

What is the right code to make it work on Firefox ?

Comment: This isn't the right place to make firefox bug reports. What specifically are you asking?

Comment: @scrappedcola It may be a firefox bug or may be not and I just missed something when I wrote my code. If it turns out to be a confirmed firefox bug, I'm going to ask elsewhere, but not before. So the question is: What is the right code to make it work on Firefox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now works on version 50.0 of Firefox, a month later.