# How to detect keyboard shortcut in JS? (In my case Alt+Z)

Tags: javascript

So on my website, I want to make a little box that shows the current mouse position only when I hold Alt+Z and disappear when I release the hotkey.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting combination keypresses (Control, Alt, Shift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557990/detecting-combination-keypresses-control-alt-shift)

Comment: I think the main problem is the showing of a box that is at the current mouse position, and combining that with the event listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for a shortcut (an event) using the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method:

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.key == "z" && event.altKey){
        console.log("Alt + Z pressed!")
        // Do some other stuff here
    }
})
```

This applies to the **entire** document; If you want to only add the listener for a certain element, this method would exist for that [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) too.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/vdwr4qcy/7/) a live `jsfiddle` demo.

Comment: Very good answer. Thanks for the jsfiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding the next method to the `document.onkeyup` event:

```
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.altKey && event.key == "z") {
    alert("ALT + Z keys were pressed");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if(e.keyCode == 90 && e.altKey) alert("Hello World!");
});
```

Comment: Alt key, not the Ctrl key

Comment: Thank you very much, I had read the question wrong - Also the snippet is a very nice touch